# libgdx android game not rendering properly

Tags: android, libgdx

My game works fine on desktop, but when I load it on an android device or the emulator I get a black screen. The game is working; I can hear the sounds and click the UI buttons. When testing on my android phone, I can turn the screen off and on again, and then the game renders fine. I would appreciate an explanation of what I'm doing wrong.

```
public class TestProject extends Game {

   GameScreen gameScreen;
   EndScreen endScreen;
   MenuScreen menuScreen;

   @Override
   public void create () {
      Gdx.app.log("TestProject", "created");
      AssetLoader.load();
      gameScreen = new GameScreen(this);
      endScreen = new EndScreen(this);
      menuScreen = new MenuScreen(this);
      setScreen(menuScreen);
   }

   @Override
   public void dispose() {
      super.dispose();
      AssetLoader.dispose();
   }
}

public class MenuScreen implements Screen{

    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    final static float GAME_WIDTH = 200;
    final static float GAME_HEIGHT = 100;
    public static final float UNIT_SCALE = 1/8f;
    static float aspectRatio;
    private OrthographicCamera cam;
    Viewport viewport;
    Stage stage;
    TestProject project;

    public MenuScreen(TestProject theProject){
        project = new TestProject();
        this.project = theProject;

        aspectRatio = (float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / (float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth();

        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();

        stage = new Stage();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new ExtendViewport(GAME_WIDTH * aspectRatio, GAME_HEIGHT, cam);
        viewport.apply();
        cam.setToOrtho(false, GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);
        cam.position.set(GAME_WIDTH / 2, GAME_HEIGHT / 2, 0);

        stage.addActor(AssetLoader.playButton);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta){
        //Clear screen
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

        AssetLoader.font.getData().setScale(.25f, -.25f);
        AssetLoader.playButton.setPosition((Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2) - AssetLoader.playButton.getWidth() / 2,
                (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 3) - AssetLoader.playButton.getHeight() / 2);

        spriteBatch.begin();

        spriteBatch.draw(AssetLoader.menuBG, 0, 0, 200, 100);

        AssetLoader.font.draw(spriteBatch, "Shark Run", 55, 85);

        spriteBatch.end();

        stage.draw();

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        AssetLoader.playButton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                project.setScreen(project.gameScreen);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is stage.act() ?

Comment: It sounds like you have `static` variables that are referencing your assets. This messes up the app's cycle, when running on `android`. E.g., is `AssetLoader` static?

Comment: I had a similar issue when my textures were not power-of-two dimensions. Some devices can handle that and some can't so just render them blank. Might be worth checking

Comment: All of my textures and animations in AssetLoader are static.  Should I change it, and then just declare an instance of the class?

Comment: @DemonicTurkey yes, get rid of the `static` reference. Dispose of it inside the `dispose` function and create a new instance in `show`.

Comment: @user2016436 That wasn't it.  All of the static variables on the assets are gone, still having the same problem.  Thanks for trying.